# Choosing an email sending service

Tags: email

I'm going to send a lot of (legitimate, not spam) emails, and would like to use an external service provider for this purpose (help track bounce rate, "marked as spam" emails, etc...).

We really need a reliable solution, that would have:

- Very low percentage of lost emails
- No mysterious delays from time of sending to the time the mail is received
- Good bulk API and a high throughput
- Good cost/email is also a factor, though I'd prefer a quality solution over a cheap one.

Which service would you use? What are the benefits of yours chosen solution?

Comment: I think this may belong in a wiki of sorts? Regardless, posted some services that did well for us below.

Comment: Say you're a programmer, and given a task "build me an email sending module". You can implement or use an SMTP server, which would be a legitimate question (how do I send emails via SMTP from java). 

Alternatively, sometimes the better choice is to use a 3rd party, and are left with the question of which 3rd party to choose. Do you think StackOverflow should not be the place for the second question?

Comment: No offense intended, I did leave an answer for you as well. I was not sure if this section is the correct one, I saw quite a few of similar questions being moved to wiki.

Comment: "this section is the correct one"? You mean, another Trilogy site?

"moved to wiki" - community wiki? I'm not sure I understand why, but I'm more interested in the answers than the reputation anyway, so that's fine by me.

Answer (score 3):

1. http://www.campaignmonitor.com
2. http://www.mailchimp.com
3. http://www.aweber.com

In order of "awesomeness", obviously.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using Campaign Monitor (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/)

It has worked well for me, has great stats, can be white labelled to give access to your clients, can run on custom domains, has a solid, easy to use interface, etc.

Its a very professional product and they are working on new features all the time.

The cost is $5 + 1c per recipient so price is very reasonable.

If you need to send a -LOT- of emails then there is also a monthly subscription model which might be even more cost effective for you.

I used to use MailChimp before I jumped ship to go to CampaignMonitor. At the time they were a long way behind CampaignMonitor but I have reviewed their site recently and they seem to have caught up and provide the same level of features as CampaignMonitor now.

One thing that we recently have come up against in CampaignMonitor is that the autoresponder rules are not very flexible. I wanted to start a database of clients off with a series of emails but if they already have the specific service then skip that newsletter. When I looked into this on CampaignMonitor I found they only offer a few basic triggers for autoresponders.

Comment: They have APIs for the various programming languages. Interesting.

Comment: And code samples on github. Me like.