# Should I use a 3rd party email sending solution or implement my own?

Tags: email

We want to send a small number of emails to our customers.
Is there an advantage is using [3rd party SOA services like ActiveTrail](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-ActiveTrail-alternatives-to-sending-email-campaigns) over implementing it ourselves?

Are there cheap services that really give an "extra oomph", and are worth considering?

The minimal requirements for such a service are:

- Not cost a ton of money for a relatively small number of emails.
- Have an easy API for sending emails, decent documentation
- Provide a real benefit like helping you manage spam/lost emails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing an email sending service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809906/choosing-an-email-sending-service)

Comment: Damn ... I googeled before asking this question, but now that I have I see some duplicates ... and mine own question from three years ago is top. Is there a name for this phenomenon?

Comment: @ ripper234: mm, bad googling skills? :-)

Comment: @ripper234 +1 because this is also useful for me :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - no, that's part of the cause, not a name for the feeling. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119584/what-do-you-call-the-feeling-of-damn-i-asked-this-three-years-ago

Comment: @Sol - thanks - this is why I always held the opinion that even duplicate questions are useful, and sometimes deserve upvotes. Different phrasing of the question can expose it to different people and make it easier to find.

Comment: You can delete you know.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading correctly, you are looking for something to manage bulk mail (newsletters and its ilk) to your customers. Luckily for you, you have plenty of choices!

The most popular of which is [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) which has a "free forever" plan which is good for up to 2,000 subscribers.

Here is a complete list of bulk mail providers:

- [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com)
- [MadMimi](http://madmimi.com)
- [AWeber](http://aweber.com)
- [Campaign Monitor](http://campaignmonitor.com)

And here is a list of other mail providers that are capable of handling bulk mail:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com)
- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [MailJet](http://mailjet.com)

Feel free to take a look at all of them and try them out. They *should* have free accounts for you to kick the tires around with, but all of them are solid alternatives.

(**FULL DISCLOSURE:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp. Happy to help you out if you have any further questions about bulk mail providers!)

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this is not really the answer I want - I want to understand what actual advantage (not ad-speak, but concrete thins) these services offer me, when the alternative is simply implementing my own email via an SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage to using a 3rd party is not worrying about your site being black listed by providers. If you are sending large quantities of emails on a regular basis, then you will regularly need to make sure you are following all the rules and keep up to date on them for bulk mail sending. Alternatively, the bulk mail senders will handle all of this for you.

You said "a small number of emails to our customers," but not knowing what regularity or size of your customer base, I cannot give a solid yes/no to the question, but it may just be easier for you to use a service like MailChimp, where it won't cost you anything if you are within their 2,000 recipients and it will make it easier for you to scale up as your business grows.